# What are all the ports that Amazon AWS recognizes?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ports

When I add ports to my EC2 Security group, some of them pop up automatically having the name of what they're used for (HTTP, POP3, SSH, etc...). Is there a list of all the ones Amazon recognizes, just in case there are any important ones that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will recognise any port you request - they're just some ones to help you get started (and because they're the most commonly used ones) - it works just the same as any other firewall, open up whatever ports you like.